# Marks needing to build error shown with the StreamProvider widget

Tags: flutter-provider

I got the error message with the following code that I was trying to use a StreamProvider on the buildContext, I have already added 'listen: false' in the initState process. Any idea how to change the code? Any where exactly was the problem?

```
  @override
  void initState() {
      final gameProvider = Provider.of<GameProvider>(context,listen :false);
      gameProvider.changeGameId = widget.game.gameId;

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final gameProvider = Provider.of<GameProvider>(context);
    //    gameProvider.changeGameId = widget.game.gameId;
    if (gameProvider == null) return Container();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('OnLine BlackJack'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Stack(
          children: [

            Positioned(
                top: 420,
                left: 1,
                height: 180,
                width: 99, //+ gameProvider.playerHandJson.length * 30,
                //duration: Duration(seconds: 1),

                child: Container(
                  child: gameProvider.playerHandJson != null
                      ? HandJsonDecode(handJson: gameProvider.playerHandJson)
                      : Container(),
                )),
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can show your `GameProvider`, will help us to understand better the problem.
Also i think you are calling a function `changeGameId` as a variable.

```
  gameProvider.changeGameId = widget.game.gameId;

  gameProvider.changeGameId(widget.game.gameId);
```

I suppouse you have somtihing like this in your provider

```
class GameProvide extend ChangeNotifier{
final _gameId;

 void function changeGameId(String id){
  _gameId = id;
  notifyListeners();
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have resolved the problem by using Streambuilder as listed in my answer, but still not sure what was the problem causing the error before.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the problme by using the StreamBuilder, but not why the changeGameId was causing the error. I did have the changeGameId function coded in the GameProvider class.

Widget build(BuildContext context) {

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('OnLine BlackJack'),
  ),
  body: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: Stack(
      children: [
        StreamBuilder<Game>(
            stream: firestoreService.joinedGame(widget.game.gameId),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              var game = snapshot.data;
              if (game != null) {
                return Stack(children: [
                  Positioned(
                      top: 1,
                      left: 1,
                      width: (game.playerHandJson.length) * 30.0 + 69,
                      height: 180,
                      child: Container(
                          child: HandJsonDecode(
                        handJson: game.playerHandJson,
                      ))),
```